# How to setup Visual Studio Code for a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code

I'm following this Spring tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I would like use Visual Studio Code as IDE.

On my machine are installed the following programs:

- Java JDK 1.8.0_221
- Gradle 5.6
- Maven 3.6.1

And these the extensions installed in VSC for support Java:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naco-siren.gradle-language

I notice that code completion not working correctly for some dependencies, like `org.springframework.boot`.

VSC shows a popup with the following warning:

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/"Classpath-is-incomplete"-warning

In addition I noticed this error throwed by Language Support for Java extension:

```
[Error - 06:17:08] 21-ago-2019 6.15.10 Error occured while building workspace. Details: 
message: SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type;code: 16777218
message: SpringApplication cannot be resolved;code: 570425394
message: The import org.springframework cannot be resolved;code: 268435846
message: The import org.springframework cannot be resolved;code: 268435846
```

How can I solve the above error and fix troubles with code completion?

Comment: you could follow the [Spring Boot](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot) official Spring tutorial,it needs to install [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and [Spring Initializr extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr)

Comment: I want fix this particular problem without using Spring specific extensions also for future external dependecies that I could install